# Angular Event handler concept for multi cloud user login and user persist

Tags: angular, authentication

I have a angular front end app with a .net core back end. Back is setup so it can successfully validate token from both AAD and Google cloud identity.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login

I am using this library on my front end to in order to show 2 button which on succesfull login give me the corresponding JWT token for either or of the two clouds.

Issue I have is that msal is not an option bc it cant work with google issued token. How would I create a Broadcast or event handler or a service in general with a subject with certain states, and then will I need another service which will subscribe to the "event handler" ?? Would that concept be valid. Also both services I assume should be injected in app.component.ts but then will that make those services "globally" avaliable, and will my User get "logged" in when I refresh and go to different pages of my app.

Issue I have is once I save the token to localStorage, if I hit F5 the state of the login varaible is lost and the user is "logged out" even tho the token in the session and local storage is still valid.